# C++ typeid(func).name return a strange string

Tags: c++

there is a c++ code :

```
void fun(){}
void fun1(int a){}
void fun2(int* a){}
void fun3(int* a, int* b){}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::cout << typeid(fun).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(fun1).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(fun2).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(fun3).name() << std::endl;
}

// console output : 
FvvE       
FviE
FvPiE
FvPiS_E
```

I can guess some results , such as :
FvvE :    a function, return type is  'void', with zero parameter ('void')
but what's the meaning of the last 'E' ?

FvPiS_E : a function, return type is 'void', with the first parameter ’int*‘
but, what's the meaning of 'S_' ?

Finally,
is there any documents about 'simple name of typeid.name()' ?

---

XCode and settings:
[image]

Comment: The name is implementation-defined, not required to be unique between types, and not even guaranteed to be the same between different invocations of the same program. (In other words, there aren't many practical uses for it.)

Comment: If you're using GCC/clang `typeid(fun).name()` will return a mangled name, you need can find how to demangle it here https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html.
On MSVC the character-string is usually human readable.

Comment: @Kaldrr Another option is c++filt. Thanks for your reply, but this is not the answer I want. I want the exact meaning of these characters.

Answer (score 1):

Through google several times, I found the answer.

```
E           : End of argument list  
S_          : substituted name  
S<digit>_   : substituted name (**repeated**)
```

see links :
[External Names (a.k.a. Mangling)](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling)
[External Name Mangling](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi-examples.html#mangling)
[C++ ABI for IA-64: Mangling](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi-mangling.html)